# Sudden CORS errors in Production

Tags: azure, cors

I have a webapp, frontend Angular, backend nest.js, deployed on Azure.

This morning it suddenly started throwing CORS errors in both Production and UAT (locally it works fine, I am not trying to make API calls from my local environment). I didn't change any settings, I didn't do any deployments.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example-backend-production.azurewebsites.net/graphql/'
from origin 'https://example-production.azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS policy:
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

In my request headers I can see this:

```
Request URL: https://example-backend-production.azurewebsites.net/graphql/
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Is this related to some Azure settings? Where should I add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header? It's been working fine for the last 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

Probably AppService settings might have got changed, go to your AppService and
enable CORS

[image]

Comment: This is not "checked" currently, I don't know what it was before. What should I add for the allow origin?

Comment: Should I do this on the frontend app settings or backend? (i have two apps)

Comment: This should be enabled for the backend unless you have not added the cors on server code

Comment: I enabled CORS and allowed origin from https://example-production.azurewebsites.net but it is sill happening

Comment: you need to add https://example-backend-production.azurewebsites.net/graphql/